# Google adsense-div size not match with official size

Tags: html, adsense

I want to use google adsense in my website. But the size of div is 240*240,and ad of google is 250*250. I am wondering how would it look like when ad size not match with my div. 
Thank for helping me.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: please share html and css your using

Comment: <div style = "width:240px;height:240px;">
  <script async src="//a link to js"></script>
 <!-- AD250*250 -->
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
      style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:250px"
      data-ad-client=""
      data-ad-slot=""></ins>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
               
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Google Ads fits in the parent DIV, but ***don’t wonder fix your DIV size so that Google Ads can perform better***

To earn good revenue use following ad units

**300x250, 300x600, 336x280 or 728x90**

***Don’t waste your time and effort in less performing ad units***

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It is really helpful.